# Custom records in Typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm using Typo3 6.1 with a custom made Fluid template. I'd be perfectly happy with the default page editor, if it had a simple way to add fields for custom records (if you know Wordpress, think of its custom fields). I did a lot of research, but ultimately I always came across a solution that outdated and no longer compatible with Typo3 6.x versions. More specifically, that solution was an extension called Kickstarter. If I got that right, that was replaced by another extension, which has been renamed at least once. That makes it rather difficult to find good information on that. (Not to mention the bad English used in Typo3's Wiki)

Anyway, here's what I'm trying to achieve. When creating a page, I'd like to maintain the standard RichText editor, but also have the option to add URLs to images (or maybe, later, other extra-information). Ideally, these custom records would be extendable, but a multiline text-field would probably be good enough.

What would be the easiest solution to modify the backend editor to suit my needs and how can I access the stored information in my Fluid template?

Comment: How are you inserting your images? Using the rich text editor (has to be explicitly enabled in the install tool), or by adding images to the content element (tab 'images')? If the latter is the case, you'd need to extend the table `sys_file_reference`. The way to do that is to build an extension that defines the new fields in the 'Table Configuration Array (TCA)'. The documentation for that array is here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should familiarize a bit more with the default content elements, I think what you are trying to do could be possible with the content element text+images and the use of the images tab.

It will however always be possible that this isn't enough, then creating an own extension will be the way to go. The old kickstarter has been replaced with the extension builder (extension key extension_builder) and will propably help you get started. Unfortunately documentation for own extensions are mostly outdated and even then not very clear. You'll have to dig through a lot of info on the web to get things worked out.

A few pointers for example code and tutorials I have come across:

- https://github.com/georgringer/modernpackage/ a template to get started with a page template as well as custom content elements
- https://github.com/akiessling/ak_accordion more custom content element examples
- https://www.mittwald.de/typo3-dokumentation/ some documentation to typo in general and extbase/fluid development in particular but only in german and a little bit outdated (looks slightly different in 6.x)

Specifically for your problem: you'll have to extend the tt_content table with a new value and provide some way to enter your new values, possibly through flexform or TCA configuration (have a look at the custom content element examples).

Hope this helps a bit, you'll sometimes have to read between the lines though.